# How can I hide/remove/disable "forums views" in vbulletin?

Tags: mysql, vbulletin

anyone have an idea how to do this.
i need to get rid of forum views either by hide, delete, disable or any other way.

Comment: What do you mean by "Forum Views" (am an ex vBulletin developer, so can probably help if I knew what you were on about!)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean THREAD views in the text below:

Do a template search for `$thread[views]`, and there should be a template called `threadbit`. If you want to quickly and easily obscure the views just delete `$thread[views]` and replace with `&nbsp;` or asterisks, or whatever you'd like.

If you want to remove the whole `<td>` it becomes more complicated. First you remove that `<td>`, and then in `FORUMDISPLAY` template you have to remove the `<td>` that contains `$vbphrase[views]` (do a search for it if you can't find it).

But I believe there may be some issue with removing that entire column, and any of the hardcoded `colspan` attributes among the templates. If so then you would have to reduce the `colspan` number by one. I'm not sure about the `colspan` part, it's been a long time since I edited the `FORUMDISPLAY` and `threadbit` templates.

Also, you will need to remove the Views from another location in the `threadbit` template:

```
title="<phrase 1="$thread[replycount]" 2="$thread[views]"
```

This shows up when you hover on top of the Last Post column. Just delete `$thread[views]` and it will show up blank.

Answer (score 1):

i need 50 points to reply, sorry for keep using answer.

i was thinking of going 1 step futher and swapping the word hidden for a picture?
I used the word hidden just as a test to see if it would work which it does